# Combine Insert from Select with sysdate on Date column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to make an insert statement from a select statement, it looks like this

```
INSERT INTO kasa.customer (ctt_id, ntt_id) 
            (SELECT ctt_id, ntt_id FROM ctt WHERE ntt_id=2242456)
```

In this insert, I would also like to set a Date column to `sysdate`. Right now I'm doing it in two steps, but I've got a feeling this should be pretty easy to combine.

```
UPDATE kasa.customer SET created_dtm=sysdate WHERE ntt_id=2242456
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO kasa.customer (ctt_id, ntt_id, created_dtm) 
            (SELECT ctt_id, ntt_id, sysdate FROM ctt WHERE ntt_id=2242456)
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I tried this myself but messed up the syntax.. =) Thanks!